# Using multiple tables in Android application using AWS DynamoDB

Tags: android, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I am using an AWS DynamoDB database for my Android application.
I am using AWS Amplify API (GraphQL API) to query and mutate.

However, I am not able to interact with two or more tables.
I want to know how to purposefully have 2 or more table use. I am new to it and can't figure out. Thanks.

Comment: How do you want to pull the data from these two tables? is the data related or not. is the data hierarchical. you need to give more info on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply create two separate schema such as :

```
type Table1 @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  posts: [Post] @connection(name: "BlogPosts")
}

type Table2 @model {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  blog: Blog @connection(name: "BlogPosts")
  comments: [Comment] @connection(name: "PostComments")
}
```

you will have a graphql folder created which will contain the sample code for mutation , update and query for both of the tables.